# Parse FileSaveError Code 130

Tags: swift, parse-platform

this is my first ever question so please let me know if I can improve anything in the future.

I am self-learning Swift and Parse. When I tried to save an image to Parse, it gave me the error as can be seen in the picture.

[Error message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbvgc.png)

The error message in the picture is as following:

**Parse::FileSaveError (Code: 130, Version: 1.11.0)**

Can someone please help me with this? I'm not familiar with Swift or Parse so I don't know if they have any certain behaviours.

Many thanks

Comment: have you checked `imageFile` column data type is it `PFFile`

Comment: @HamzaAnsari yes I've checked it on Parse and it s the correct file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition for the error code you are receiving is:

"Error code indicating that a unique field was given a value that is already taken."

As your code appears to be valid, the issue is most likely in the Parse database itself. Go into Parse core and remove the "Post" class you have created and try running the code again.

It is worth noting that it can help to use print(error) to print the actual error out rather than just a string.

Comment: Hi Ben, I noticed that the size of default images in the  iOS simulator is somehow a bit big coz it takes a while to upload them to Parse. I saved an image directly from safari on the simulator and uploaded it and it worked perfectly fine. I tried to upload it again for a few times and it worked too(same image). I then tried to upload the default images on the simulator, and it worked this time. I'm still trying to figure it out what exactly happened... Thanks for your answer and the tip :)

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! I think I've had the same thing happen to me in the past, Parse really need to throw clearer errors!